# Installing Eclipse Mosquitto into environment

Tags: deployment, package, mosquitto

I am building a deployment environment so the user doesn't need to worry about setting anything up on their end.

For example, I am using python's embeddable zip as part of this environment, so the user doesn't need to worry about installing python.

I would like to do the same for Mosquitto, but I can't find any zipped binaries for Mosquito for Windows.

Is this possible, or will the user need to install Mosquitto independently?

Answer (score 1):

The project only makes the Installer available for Windows, but there is nothing to stop you building it yourself and zipping up the output.

Details on building are available on the github page [here](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto)